# Stuck implementing "man went to mow" rhyme in Python for my homework

Tags: python

We have to write a program that will be like the kids rhyme one man went to mow. We have to do this using lists. My teacher isn't so worried about the correct english of man and men.

This is a link of the rhyme http://www.kididdles.com/lyrics/o105.html

This is what I have so far...

```
men = input ('enter how many men you would like to mow the meadow')
menmow = 1
menlist = []
while menmow <men:
   print str(menmow) + ' man went to mow'
   print 'went to mow a meadow'
   print 'one man and his dog'
   print 'went to mow a meadow'
   menlist.insert [0.2]
if menmow >men:
   print 'your meadow has been mowed'
```

Comment: When you run your code you probably end up with a stack trace.  What does it say?

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the update. I guess I need to visit meta more often. Thanks for giving me something ELSE to suck up my free time =p (I hope the net doesn't drop the sarcasm packet.)

Comment: Welcome! It will help if you describe what your code is currently doing, how it differs from what you want it to do, and where you're getting stuck. It's also helpful to give a short example of the desired output in your question. The page you linked to could go away in the future, and then this question would be less useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you have an infinite loop (the while loop will never terminate).

Answer (score 1):

You are quite far like this. Some details are wrong, which you will discover while testing. What is missing is the correct implementation of the line "one man and his dog". This should change for each couplet.

What you can do is create a second loop to output One man, Two man etc. Hint: `print "text",` will print text, but supress the newline.

As an alternative, you can use a for loop to build up the text as a list, and then output that. Like in your main loop you can keep a counter and append `str(counter) + " man"` to the list.
To output this list as a string, use `' '.join(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2.x, then the `input()` function will *execute* the statement as if it were Python code.  That's probably not what you want.  Also, you attempt to do `menmow < men`, which will be an invalid comparison between an int and a String.

Change your input statement to this:

```
men = int(raw_input ('enter how many men you would like to mow the meadow'))
```

You will also need a statement to end your loop.  It will run indefinitely, since the loop condition doesn't care about `menlist`.

Lastly, `menlist.insert [0.2]` isn't valid syntax.  Be sure to check on how you insert values into a list.

Comment: Well, actually, if he inputs an integer to `input`, then `men` is an integer so `menmow < men` is fine. (Nitpick: the string type is called `str` in Python)

Answer (score 0):

`menlist.insert[0.2]` is invalid; you will end up with a cryptic error like `'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.

As `insert` is a function, use the function call syntax: `menlist.insert(0, 2)` to insert `2` at the start of the list (at index `0`).

Answer (score 0):

- You can simplify your `while` loop by just using a `for` loop and a `range()` object.
- Use functions. They are your friends.
- Join the contents of a list together using `', '.join(your_list)`

Here's how I'd tackle the problem:

```
def lyrics(men):
  verses = []

  verses.append(str(len(men)) + ' men went to mow,')
  verses.append('Went to mow a meadow,')
  verses.append(', '.join(reversed(men)) + ' and his dog,')

  return '\n'.join(verses)

num_men = int(raw_input('How many men will mow the meadow? '))

song = []
men = []

for man in range(1, num_men + 1):
  men.append(str(man) + ' men')
  song.append(lyrics(men))

print '\n\n'.join(song)
print
print 'your meadow has been mowed'
```

To actually make your code spit out the real song (with spelled-out numbers), use a dictionary to map numbers to words:

```
num_men = int(raw_input('How many men will mow the meadow? '))

def lyrics(men):
    return '{num_men} went to mow,\nWent to mow a meadow,\n{men} and his dog'.format(
      num_men=len(men),
      men=', '.join(reversed(men)).capitalize()
  )

song = []
men = []

numbers = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
    4: 'four',
    5: 'five',
    6: 'six',
    7: 'seven',
    8: 'eight',
    9: 'nine'
}

for man in range(1, num_men + 1):
    men.append('{} {}'.format(numbers[man], 'man' if man == 1 else 'men'))
    song.append(lyrics(men))

print '\n\n'.join(song)
print
print 'your meadow has been mowed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problem, and decided to try it, just for the heck. Here's what I came up with.
Since the user input has to be digits, you need to create a **dictionary** to map the digits to numbers (in words, e.g. 1 becomes **one**). And in order to create a dictionary, you need to know the **maximum** value a user will enter. 
**OR** 
Use the digits just like that, instead of the numbers in words. 
I chose the second option; here's the code; feel free to mess with it.

```
def one_man():
    return """
            One man went to mow,\n
            Went to mow a meadow, \n
            One man and his dog, \n
            Went to mow a meadow.\n
```

```
      """;
```

def many_men(num_of_men, collated_men):
    return """
            {0} men went to mow,\n
            Went to mow a meadow, \n
            {1} 1 man and his dog, \n
            Went to mow a meadow.\n
          """ . format(num_of_men, collated_men);

def collate_men(num_of_men):
    result = "";
    while num_of_men > 1:
        result += "{0} men, " . format(num_of_men);
        num_of_men -= 1;
    return result;

if **name** == "**main**":
    preamble = """ To exit this program, type y or n when prompted""";
    print preamble;

`loop = True;
while loop:

    preamble = raw_input("""Want to exit the program? y/n : """);
    if preamble == "y":
        loop = False;
        break;
    else:
        num_of_men_value = raw_input("""Enter the number of men you would like to mow the meadow with?: """);
        try:
            num_of_men = int(num_of_men_value);
            if num_of_men < 1:
                    print "Digit must be greater than 0";
            elif num_of_men == 1:
                    print one_man();
            else:
                    collated_men = collate_men(num_of_men);
                    print many_men(num_of_men, collated_men);
            continue;    
        except:
            print  "Number must be a valid digit";
            continue;`